How to put a dictionary into the clipboard to copy/paste it in another pyqt6 window?
I would like to use the clipboard to pass a dict from a Qapplication to another.
I can copy a text, but I don't understand how I can pass something else. I need to pass a dict instead of a text.
Here is a minimal example where I can launch the software twice and copy the text to the other one:
import sys
import numpy as np
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *


class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.centralWidget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        self.mainHBOX = QVBoxLayout()

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.Text_EL = QLineEdit('Some Text')
        self.Copy_PB = QPushButton('Copy to ClipBoard')
        self.Paste_PB = QPushButton('Paste from ClipBoard')


        self.layout.addWidget(self.Text_EL)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Copy_PB)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.Paste_PB)

        self.mainHBOX.addLayout(self.layout)


        self.centralWidget.setLayout(self.mainHBOX)
        self.centralWidget.setFixedSize(QSize(300,400))
        self.Copy_PB.clicked.connect(self.Copy_fun)
        self.Paste_PB.clicked.connect(self.Paste_fun)


    def Copy_fun(self):
        # copy into clipboard
        text = self.Text_EL.text()

        # send a dictionary instead of a string
        MyDict = {'text':text}

        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        cb.clear(mode=QClipboard.Mode.Clipboard)
        cb.setText(text, mode=QClipboard.Mode.Clipboard)

    def Paste_fun(self):
        # Paste from clipboard
        cb = QApplication.clipboard()
        text = cb.text()
        self.Text_EL.setText(text)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

I tried something with QMimeData but it seems that it cannot handle dict
def Copy_fun(self):
    # copy into clipboard
    text = self.Text_EL.text()

    # send a dictionary instead of a string
    MyDict = {'text':text}

    clipboard = QGuiApplication.clipboard()
    data = QMimeData()
    data.setData(MyDict)
    clipboard.setMimeData(data, mode=QClipboard.Mode.Clipboard)


QClipboard stores MIME type objects, so generic Python objects (like dictionaries) are not a valid data type for it. You can serialise a dictionary to e.g. JSON string using json.dumps and then recreate an object from it on the other side with json.parse.

Thanks, Here I used text as an example but I would like to passe some vectors. Does json the right option?

If vectors can be serialised (e.g. as list of numbers) then yes.
